# Java - Launch4j NoClassDefFoundError with additional library

Tags: java, launch4j

In Netbeans 8.1,
After I Clean and Build my Java app (Desktop Application), I got my app.jar in dist folder.
Then i want to take those app.jar to become app.exe using [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

The problem is, in my app, I use this library [java telegram](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/releases) . 
If I double clicked directly to app.jar, everything is OK, my app can send message to telegram.
But why, when it becomes .exe,  I got

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pengrad/telegrambot/request/BaseRequest
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do you use a dedicated maven plugin for `exe` file creation? Is `java-telegram` the only external library that you use?

Comment: No, I am not using maven. Yes, only java-telegram

Comment: How do you build your app then? `ant`, `gradle`, `javac`?

Comment: As we create Java SE application in netbeans, its said Standard Projects us an IDE-generated Ant build script

Comment: The problem is that `java-telegram` lib is not in a runtime classpath. You can workaround it in two ways: 
1) Create a fat-jar (jar with all dependencies included) 
2) In `Launch4j` you have a `Classpath` tab - check `Custom classpath`, provide full qualified class name in `Main class` field and add a `java-telegram` library as an entry into `Classpath` list. It should be a relative path to that lib.

Comment: Okey,second ways look promising

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Maciej

In Launch4j you have a Classpath tab - check Custom classpath, provide full qualified class name in Main class field and add a java-telegram library as an entry into Classpath list. It should be a relative path to that lib